# RemoveChild when onclick() only on parent (outside of element)

Tags: javascript, removechild, clonenode

How to avoid `closeWindow()` call on `#window`? Currently `#window-overlay` is removed with all nested childs when clicked anywhere on screen. But i want to do this only when clicked on `#window-overlay` and not to `#window`. So `#window` could have its own click events.
I am absolute noob in JS. Just trying to do modal kind stuff without using `display:block`, etc... Idea is simple, no matter what, my window always will be on top of everything else as it is appended to `document.body` and i don't need to care much about z-index collisions and other stuff. As well, cloneNode is pretty performant. I know, my functions are not reusable, but i will deal with this later. Probably i need to deal with `e.stopPropagation()` but not sure how to implement this.

```
<template id="my-test">
    <div id="window-overlay" class="my-test" onclick="closeWindow()">
        <div id="window" class="window">
            <p>My Window</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

function openProfile() {
    var myTest = document.querySelector('#my-test').content;
    document.body.appendChild(myTest.cloneNode(true));
}

function closeWindow() {
    var wo = document.querySelector('#window-overlay');
    var root = document.body
    root.removeChild(wo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click action is being propagated from your #window component through your #window-overlay.

Then, you need to stop this propagation, and you can do it this way

```
<template id="my-test">
    <div id="window-overlay" class="my-test" onclick="closeWindow()">
        <div id="window" class="window" onclick="e => e.stopPropagation()">
            <p>My Window</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

If you need to do other things when clicking in your #window component, then you could define its own function, for example

```
<template id="my-test">
    <div id="window-overlay" class="my-test" onclick="closeWindow()">
        <div id="window" class="window" onclick="foo(event)">
            <p>My Window</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


function foo(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();

     // your stuff here ...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank You!. Second case helped me. Except that you didn't mentioned, that i need to call it `onclick="foo(event)"`  (event argument should be passed).

Comment: Is this `e.stopPropagation();` something similar to `!important` from CSS world which means that something is now quite good with construction and it should be avoided? Shortly - does this smell?

Comment: You are right! I missed that when I wrote the solution. Now I added for future readers.. Sorry to mention but it's not the same concept of !important, not even close.. When you do click on an element, the click actions over that component, and the event propagates to every parent, and that's why you had this behaviour.

On the other hand, !important means that such spec must be prioritized than others that doesn't have it in them. Was I clear?

Comment: Thank You. I was not clear with my last Q. I was trying to ask is this `e.stopPropagation();` something from "bad practices" world and i should avoid it in general?

Comment: Not at all, depends the case it would be useful and correct to use. With e.stopPropagation you are telling HTML that the event only is applying to the child, and you don't want to instantiate parent's action. You can use return false in your function handler as well, and this is more common to see. Nevertheless you are good asking yourself that question! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can change he ID of this element something else like this

```
document.querySelector('#window-overlay').id = "somethingelse";
```

and you did not need to remove the child only change the id of this element
remove this line
root.removeChild(wo);